# Is "catch (Exception NullPointerException)" the same as writing "catch (NullPointerException e)"?

Tags: java

I recently included a simple try catch statement in an assignment, and I wrote it as follows

```
try { ... }
catch (Exception NullPointerException) { ... }
```

Is this functionally the same as writing:

```
try { ... }
catch (NullPointerException e) { ... }
```

The code ran fine when I tested it, but I wanted to make sure I am grasping the way catch statements work correctly. Are both these formats viable?

Comment: No, they are not the same. In the first case, the code catches all `Exception`s (including `NullPointerException`s) in a variable called `NullPointerException`. In the second case, the code catches all `NullPointerException`s in a variable called `e`.

Comment: Also, if you're writing code that catches null pointer exceptions, you're probably doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2):

**Firstly,**

The first block indicates that it is capable to handle any type of exception.

```
try{//code here}
catch(Exception NullPointerException){//code here}
```

While the second block indicates that it can handle only NullPointerException type of exception.

```
try{//code here}
catch(NullPointerException e){//code here}
```

**Secondly,**

There is no difference between `*NullPointerException*` in first block and `*e*` in second block. They are ultimately reference variables. It can be renamed or changed to any random name. It's behavior would be always same.

Answer (score 1):

Its always

```
catch (ExceptionClass exceptionVariableName)
```

which says "catch exceptions of type `ExceptionClass` or its descendants and assign it to a variable `exceptionVariableName`

In your examples, in first case `catch(Exception NullPointerException)` `Exception` is the class and `NullPointerException` is non conventional variable name.

Second case `catch(NullPointerException e)`
`NullPointerException` is an exception class and `e` is a variable name.